# Doubling winch force to gain speed - is it possible?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, speed

It's very common to use pulleys or snatch blocks to double the "winching power" - reduce the force needed to move a particular load, at the expense of the speed, given a constant winching rate.

However I was wondering if the opposite can be implemented that is:
given a winch that has plenty of force and a comparatively light load, is it possible to rig a system so that the speed is increased (doubled instead of the classic halving)?

Comment: For vehicle winches, some folks with an auxiliary battery rig the electronics so they can switch between 12V and 24V driving the winch to speed it up on light loads (check your winch specs first!). Or one can use gearing.

Comment: OK but that changing the winch (or the winching parameters) is not really the focus of this question, I was wondering if force and speed increase can be obtained with pulleys instead of the more usual decrease

Answer (score 2):

Take a pulley which originally you can lift things with 1/4 of the weight, then put  whatever you want to have faster at the end which you usually pull and move the end where the weight has been, then it moves with 4 times the speed. the hook at the left moves 4 times as fast as the weight at he bottom, since you lengthen 4 string parts ar the same time
 this is for example used to accelerate gliders it is called reverse pulley method.[image: pully]

Comment: Oh interesting, I need to look up a graphical representation to see how it'd work

Comment: Thanks for adding the image; in that context there is a 4x increase in speed by using 4 pulleys; provided the winch is moved to the location with the black weight... I will now lookup a simpler case with the minimum amount of pulleys